# How to save manual change after a update using Entity framework designer?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using entity framework designer to build entities. I found the designer really hard to use because it overwrite all your manually change after each model update using the designer. How did you round off this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sorts of things are you manually changing? The entity still has to be mappable to the database schema.

You can extend or add functionality by declaring a partial class.

Don't make any change to the entities in the generated file -- I think it says that in the header.

All of the entities are generated as `partial` classes, which means you can declare "more" of the class elsewhere.

Here is an example:

```
public partial class Name
{
   public string First { get; set; }
}

public partial class Name
{
   public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

Although I have two different class declarations, potentially in different files and folders within the project, it gets compiled as one class.

I can now use the `Name` class like this:

```
var name = new Name();
name.First = "Jane";
name.Last = "Doe";
```

As you can see, the properties from both declarations are unified in an object of type `Name`.

To apply this to EF, leave the partial entity class alone, and declare a separate partial class with the same name to add functionality.

Comment: I don't want some of the lookup tables to be mapped as navigation property. So I removed those MSL CSDL content in the edmx.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative third-party tool. For more information, refer [this](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/producttour.html). Currently, Devart Entity Developer doesn't include the Update From Database functionality. The Update From Database feature is on our roadmap.